# Hospitality - the receiving party is <..>

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

I'm looking for a word, or a phrase, to describe being the (in my case very pleased) recipient of hospitality.  I know 'hospitalised' is not it, but it was too humorous not to mention in this context.

Is there a word or phrase for this that anyone knows that is not 'grateful' and 'pleased'?

Comment: served, waited upon? exactly what kind of "hospitality" are you asking about?

Comment: *Being a recipient of hospitality* is not the same thing as being *grateful* or *pleased*. Can you write a sentence with a blank where you want the word to go? That is not much context, but at least it clarifies what your asking for...

Answer (score 3):

I'm not certain exactly which kind of word you're looking for, but here are some that might help:

The word for a recipient of hospitality is a **guest**. Those providing the hospitality are **hosts**, and the thing they're doing is **hosting**. A good host is often described as **gracious**, a good guest as **welcome**.

Answer (score 0):

The word you may be looking for is

> appreciative

when leaving the host's party for the evening, one might say

> Thank you. It was a great party. I appreciate your hospitality.

Answer (score -1):

The closest one I can think of is:

**Greeted** - [TheFreeDictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/greeted)

> 1. To salute or welcome in a friendly and respectful way with speech or writing, as upon meeting or in starting a letter.

Which you could use like this:

> I was very kindly **greeted** by this family full of generosity.

But the meaning changes a bit, and I can't seem to find a straight synonym for your request.